# vim: Changing directory where views are saved on Windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, view

I've recently learnt about folding in vim and that you can use `:mkview` to save the folds in a document. However, vim is trying to save views in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\` directory path, which needs Admin privileges to save to... as this is a corporate Win7 work machine, I need to convince vim it wants to save views elsewhere.

Is there a command I need to include in my `_vimrc` file to get vim to save the views elsewhere? Or another way to control this behaviour?

Comment: Come on, the answer is right there in `:help :mkview`.

Comment: @romainl Reading and navigating the vim documentation via `:help` is almost an expertise all on its own.  Glib "RTFM" comments aren't helpful, and serve mostly to discourage fledgling vim users from seeking out help and becoming more powerful users.  And in the more general case, they make stackoverflow seem like a place filled with smug and unapproachable people that will ridicule newbies for asking for help rather than guiding them toward a better understanding of software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `viewdir`.
From `:help mkview` :

```
When [file] is omitted or is a number from 1 to 9, a name is generated and 'viewdir' prepended.
```

---

`:help 'viewdir'` gives:

```
                        *'viewdir'* *'vdir'*
'viewdir' 'vdir'    string  (default for Amiga, MS-DOS, OS/2 and Win32:
                         "$VIM/vimfiles/view",
                         for Unix: "~/.vim/view",
                         for Macintosh: "$VIM:vimfiles:view"
                         for VMS: "sys$login:vimfiles/view"
                         for RiscOS: "Choices:vimfiles/view")
                    global
                    {not available when compiled without the |+mksession|
                    feature}
    Name of the directory where to store files for |:mkview|.
    This option cannot be set from a |modeline| or in the |sandbox|, for
    security reasons.
```